# How to keep a rolling counter on unique dates in SQL? (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a Customer field and a Date field, and I want my data to look like this:

```
Customer | Date  | Count 
=========================
 Frank   | 02/01 |  1 
 Frank   | 03/22 |  2
 Frank   | 12/20 |  3
 Mary    | 01/14 |  1
 Mary    | 05/15 |  2
 Mary    | 11/28 |  3
 Mary    | 12/01 |  4 
 Vince   | 06/09 |  1
 Vince   | 09/09 |  2
```

Basically a consecutive counter per Customer and per Date.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using `Row_Number()`:

```
SELECT Customer, Date, Row_Number() Over (Partition By Customer Order By Date) RN
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Customer, Date
```

---

In order to account for ties, but keep the sequential numbers, try using `Dense_Rank()` instead of `Row_Number()`.

Comment: Awesome! This did it. Thanks for the quick and easy reply. Appreciate it!

Comment: @vdiddy -- np, glad I could help.

Comment: One quick follow-up: How can I account for duplicate dates? What if I want to assign them the same Count going forward?

Comment: @vdiddy -- I think `Dense_Rank()` is what you're looking for.